# Fill down formula in column gives 400 error

Tags: vbscript

I am going to be splitting an incorrect url string in a column and need to use a formula to split it into separate columns.  I have an empty column "H" next to column "G" which holds the incorrect url strings.  Below you will see that I am trying to set "leftURL" to a formula and then copy it down the entire column. This works fine using regular Excel but when I try to do it as VBScript I get a 400 error:

```
Sub formulaLeft()
Worksheets("Feed Original").Activate

Dim lngLastRow As Long
Dim leftURL As Variant
leftURL = "=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH('%20',G2)),(LEFT(G2,FIND('%20',G2)-1)),G2)"

Sheets("Feed Original").Range("H2").Value = leftURL
lngLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Range("H2:H" & lngLastRow).Value = leftURL
End Sub
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think it has something to do with the first line with 'leftURL =' (6th line of code). You may need double quotes on either side of the single quotes inside your formula.  I am trying to do something similar and my version of the script runs but does not fill in the cells down the column.

Comment: Also in the Dim declarations take out the 'as Long' and 'as Variant'. These are not valid in VBScript.